# How to show selected node on content picker to front page

Tags: umbraco

I want to create a selection of banner with Content Picker' to select node to use other banner. http://screencast.com/t/3gb6TeAe

Now I wonder how to show the selected banner on Content Picker and show it in front page. Any idea to make it in easy way.

I have tried already to get the Url of selected node.

```
var nodeId = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("selectBanner");
var node = Umbraco.TypedContent(nodeId);
<a href="@node.Url">@node.Name</a>
```

Comment: What version of Umbraco?

Comment: Does the `Banner` node consist of Image? You probably need to get the *image url* and not *node url*

Comment: @ProNotion my umbraco version is 7.2.6

Comment: `Umbraco.Media(node.GetPropertyValue("imagePickerAlias")).Url`

Comment: `Umbraco.Media(nodeId).Url;` will give you the image URL. Try it. Also [Refer](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/razor/30300-Get-a-media-url-and-name-with-Razor)

Comment: Hi if i have my media picker on banner child here: screencast.com/t/lQDPhQODdc and the purpose of the parent Banner is picking a banner child content to use it in my front page banner using Content picker screencast.com/t/3gb6TeAe. and how can i render my content picker in my template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is correct you first need to get the banner node:

```
// This gets the node selected by your content picker
var bannerNode = Umbraco.TypedContent(Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<int>("selectBanner"));
```

You then need to get the image specified on the banner node:

```
// This gets you the image/media set on the banner nodes media picker property
var img =  Umbraco.Media(bannerNode.GetPropertyValue("mediaPickerPropertyAlias")).Url
```

You can then access either the bannerNode url:

```
@bannerNode.Url
```

or the image specified on the banner node:

```
@img.Url
```

Comment: thanks! ProNotion :) showing media picker image is working. hm if i want pick a textstring on banner child. how do i retrieve that?

Comment: Do you mean on the selected child? If so... ```bannerNode.GetPropertyValue<string>("textstringPropertyAlias")```. Don't forget to vote for answers you found useful please.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand you have a Media Picker in your Banner document type. So you need to access banners image Url... you can do following

```
var node = Model.Content; // Your content of type banner
var imgUrl = Umbraco.Media(node.GetPropertyValue("selectBanner")).Url // getting property for image and then its url
<a href="@imgUrl">@node.Name</a>
```

or if you want to show just image

```
<img src="@imgUrl"/>
```

Comment: Hi if i have my media picker on banner child 
here: http://screencast.com/t/lQDPhQODdc
and the purpose of the parent Banner is picking a banner child content to use it in my front page banner using Content picker http://screencast.com/t/3gb6TeAe.
and how can i render my content picker in my template?

Comment: if your `Model.Content` is of parent Banner then your node will become `Model.Content.Children()` and you will iterate through each in nodes to get their properties.